# Nested Form Gem throws "undefined method"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, nested-forms, multi-level

I'm new to Nested Forms. I'm building a form where Companies can create Promos as under a few Categories.  I keep getting undefined method "model_id" for Class. My codes and exact error messages are as below :-

Error Message:-

```
   undefined method `category_id' for #<Company:0x007fd43828b6f8>
     <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {include_blank: 'Choose Category'}, required: true %>
<%= render partial: 'promo', locals: {f: f}%>
```

Models :-

```
   class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :users, :through => :company_customers
      has_many :company_users
      has_many :categories, :through => :category_companies
      has_many :category_companies

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :category_companies
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories s
    end


    class CompanyCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :company
      belongs_to :category
    end


    class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :company_categories
      has_many :companies, :through => :company_categories
      has_many :promos

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_categories 

      end

    class Promo < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :category
    end
```

Controller :-

```
     class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
      def new
         @company = Company.new

      end


      def create
        @company = Company.new(company_params)

      respond_to do |format|
       if @company.save
         format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company was successfully created.' }
         format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @company }
       else
         format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end  
      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
     def set_company
      @company = Company.find(params[:id])
     end


   def company_params
      params.require(:company).permit(:company_name, :registration_no, :address, :phone_no, :outlet_location, company_categories_attributes: [:id, :company_id, :category_id, category_attributes:[:id, :name, promo_attribute:[:id, :name, :description]]])
   end
   end
```

View:-

```
    <%= form_for(:company) do |f| %>
      <div class="medium-6 columns">

         <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {include_blank: 'Choose Category'}, required: true %>
         <%= render partial: 'promo', locals: {f: f}%>
      </div>

      <div class="actions">
       <%= f.submit %>
     </div>
     <% end %>
```

_promo.html.erb

```
      <%= f.fields_for :promos do |promo| %>    
       <h4 class="text-center">Promotions to be offered</h4><br>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="medium-6 columns">
         <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name", required: true %>
        </div>
        <div class="medium-6 columns">
            <%= f.text_field :description, placeholder: "Description", required: true %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>

  <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add More Promos", :promos %> </p>
```

Appreciate the help. Many Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select), the collection_select has the following use:

> collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})

They have this example:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  def name_with_initial
    "#{first_name.first}. #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

Which would be used like this:

```
collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial, prompt: true)
```

So, when you do:

```
f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {include_blank: 'Choose Category'}, required: true
```

I think maybe you're missing the `object` argument? Like, where they have `:post`.